# Response time limit in SQLite

Tags: objective-c, ios, performance, sqlite

Is there way to limit response time on SQLite?

I have SQL request, which executes from 0 to 10 seconds depends on device performance. This SQL is OPTIONAL. If request takes more than 3 sec, it should be terminated. I would prefer do not run this SQL if I could know apriori that it takes more than 3 sec.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`sqlite3_progress_handler`](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/progress_handler.html) interface to register a callback function.

As @JeremyP suggested, you can pass in a a pointer to `NSDate`, or something else storing time as context to compare against. If it reaches above a certain threshold then return a non-zero value from the callback registered with this function to terminate the operation.

```
int progressHandler(void *context) {
    NSDate *start = (NSDate *)context;
    NSTimeInterval wait = -[start timeIntervalSinceNow];

    if (wait > 3.0) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

The second argument to this function is how often your callback should be invoked. This value is in # of jump opcodes executed and will vary by machine. For context, on my Macbook, it processes around 20 million opcodes every second. A decent number for your use-case might be 10K-100K.

```
sqlite3_progress_handler(db, 100000, &progressHandler, (void *)someDate);
```

Comment: Why do you need the NSTimer?  The callback function takes a void* parameter that you can use to pass it (a pointer to) the time at which the query started.

Comment: You are right. Don't need the NSTimer. Feel free to update the answer.